# not self explicable 1064 error trying to use MEMBER OF in a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a query where I select some rows of a table based on their ID.

`SELECT id,hotel_name FROM hotel WHERE id IN (1,2)` and this works fine.
It returns two rows from hotel, id 1 and id 2 as expected. IDs in the where clause are hardcoded but data are coming from another table where they are stored in a json column as `["1","2"]`. On a normal table i'd have done I'd have done `(WHERE id in (SELECT ...)` so I tried to replace the IN operator whith MEMBER OF that should behave like IN for JSON columns.

```
SELECT id,hotel_name FROM hotel 
WHERE id MEMBER OF (
    SELECT details FROM auth_events 
    WHERE auth_events.id_user=1 AND auth_events.id_auth_catalog=10 
);
```

but I get

> Syntax error in the query next to 'SELECT details FROM auth_events WHERE auth_events.id_user=1 AND auth_events.id_a'

but I don't understand exactly what is raising it. The inner query `SELECT details FROM auth_events WHERE auth_events.id_user=1 AND auth_events.id_auth_catalog=10` is returning correctly the `["1","2"]` array.

Can anyone help me understand what am I doing wrong? Also note that my mysql version is 8.0.26 and MEMBER OF is available since 8.0.13 so this shouldn't be the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operand of `MEMBER OF` must be scalar JSON array, not a rowset.

Use

```sql
SELECT id,hotel_name 
FROM hotel 
JOIN auth_events ON auth_events.id_user=1 
                AND auth_events.id_auth_catalog=10
                AND hotel.id MEMBER OF (auth_events.details);
```

PS. The `MEMBER OF()` operator was added in MySQL 8.0.17, not in 8.0.13.

Comment: yes, you are right, was a typo... thanks for spotting the light!